# Database MN relationship

Tags: sql, database

I'm taking a class on database management systems (absolute beginner) and I'm working on a  database for a very simple blog system.

I have a question regarding one M:N relationship between blog posts and categories where the posts belong (one blog posts can be in several categories.)

The part of the scheme looks like this:
[Scheme](http://creo-preview.xf.cz/blog_posts.jpg)

I know that somehow this scheme allows to add a blog post that doesn't belong to any category. However, I don't know why that is. Could someone please explain this to me?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [One blog post in multiple categories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17262960/one-blog-post-in-multiple-categories)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably a combination of two things.  One would be a lack of referential integrity in your database design, ie you need foreign keys.  The other would be that your front end application is allowing blogs without categories to be posted.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is just a conceptual scheme. I also have a physical model with a "joiner" table that joins BLOG_POSTS and CATEGORIES. The joiner table contains two foreign keys - post_id and cat_id.

Answer (score 0):

Because you can add a blog_posts record without having to add an associated post_cat record.