# One blog post in multiple categories

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design

I'm having difficulties with the following database schema:

[image]

I know that, for some reason, this model allows me to add a blog post that doesn't belong to any category. Could someone please tell me why that is?

Comment: Are you asking why someone would want that, or how it accomplishes that?

Comment: You have already asked this question once here: [Database MN relationship](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232233/database-mn-relationship) Please don't keep entering the same question as new questions.

Comment: Do you want the posts to be assignable to multiple categories or just a single category?

Comment: Since this question has an accepted answer, I would rather close the other question and keep this one open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your `BLOG_POST` entity does not have direct relationship with `CATEGORIES`.

If you are looking to achieve that, then you should add a new field in the `BLOG_POST`, named e.g. `ID_CATEGORY`, as NOT NULLABLE,  and being a foreign-key of `CATEGORIES` table.